# Creating a pair from Python DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

[image]

Please find the image of my python dataframe.

Expected Output: A pairing of Developer and Tester from random team but not same team. And same team and role cannot be consecutive

```
{
Person1: Person6,
Person4: Person9,
......
}
```

For example sake I have posted small dataset. But we can extend the dataset

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow")! It is very difficult to answer your question without seeing the code that you have written that produces your problem. Please read about how to ask a good question and try to post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") so we can better help you.

Comment: I am a newbie to python and haven't been able to comeuppance with an appropriate approach hence raised this here tonseek ideas.

Comment: Saying you are a newbie, is not an excuse it is a crutch.  The only way to learn is to try.  That being said, start by writing down the steps you would follow if you had to manually pick paired members. For example (1) select a developer, (2) filter list to isolate testers and remove all testers from the team of the selected developer, (3) from the remaining testers select a tester.  Once you have the approach written down try to implement, add your code to your question and refine the question to ask a specific question